# cors problem while using stripe and using different servers while using Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cors, stripe-payments

I have a router which uses Router.express(). Backend runs at 5000 and frontend 3000. I have a button which has fetch(http://localhost:5000/create-checkout-session)in the frontend folder. In backend I have a payment.js folder inside api folder.In payment.js, I have used Router.post to create the checkout session. I have cors in server.js folder which has app=express() and app.listen(5000). But I am still getting error in cors.

In client side :

```
<button  className="checkoutTOpayment" onClick={()=>{
                  fetch("http://localhost:5000/create-checkout-session",{
                     method:"POST",
                    headers:{
                      "content-type" : "application/json"
                    },
                    body:JSON.stringify({
                      items: [
                        { id :1,quantity :2},
                        { id: 2,quantity:1},
                      ],
                    }),
                  })
                  .then(res=> {
                    if(res.ok) return res.json()
                    return res.json().then(json=>Promise.reject(json))
                  })
                  .then(({ url }) => {
                    window.location = url
                  })
                  .catch(e=>{
                    console.error(e.error)
                  })
                 }}
                  >
                      Checkout for payment
                </button>
```

In payments.js in backend :

```
const express = require('express');
const Router = express.Router();
const config = require('config');
//const cors = require("cors");
const stripe= require("stripe")(config.get('STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY'));  

const storeItems = new Map([
    [1, { priceInCents : 20000, name : "Bed Table"}],
    [2, { priceInCents : 30000, name : "Table "}],
])

Router.post("/create-checkout-session",async(req,res,next) => {
    try{
        console.log("Backend running");
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            payment_method_types:["card"],
            mode : "payment",
            shipping_address_collection : {
                allowed_countries : ['NP'],
            },
            shipping_options : [
                {
                    shipping_rate_data : {
                        type : 'fixed_amount',
                        fixed_amount : {
                            amount : 0,
                            currency : 'usd',
                        },
                        display_name : 'Free shipping',
                        delivery_estimate : {
                            minimum : {
                                unit : 'day',
                                value : 3,
                            },
                            maximum : {
                                unit : 'day',
                                value : 5,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    shipping_rate_data : {
                        type : 'fixed_amount',
                        fixed_amount : {
                            amount : 1500,
                            currency : 'usd',
                        },
                        display_name : "Next day air",
                        delivery_estimate : {
                            minimum : {
                                unit:'day',
                                value:1
                            },
                            maximum : {
                                unit : 'day',
                                value : 1,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
            line_items :  req.body.items.map(item => {
                const storeItem = storeItems.get(item.id)
                return {
                    price_data : {
                        currency : "usd",
                        product_data : {
                            name : storeItem.name,
                        },
                        unit_amount : storeItem.priceInCents,
                    },
                    quantity:item.quantity,
                }
            }),
            success_url : `${config.get("CLIENT_URL")}/dashboard`,
            cancel_url : `${config.get("CLIENT_URL")}/additems`,
        })
        res.json({url:session.url})
    }catch(e) {
        res.status(500).json({error:e.message})
    }
})

module.exports = Router;
```

In server.js in backend :

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const usersRouter = require("./routes/api/users");
const AddProduct = require("./routes/api/addItem");
const Payment = require("./routes/api/payment");
const config = require('config');
const app = express();
// Body parser middleware
app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    })
);
app.use(express.json());
// DB Config
const db = config.get('mongoURI');
// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
    .connect(
        db, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        }
    )
    .then(() => console.log("MongoDB successfully connected"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
// Passport config
require("./config/passport")(passport);


app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin,X-requested-With,content-type,Accept"
    );
    res.setHeader('Acess-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE');
    next();
});

// Routes
app.use("/api/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/api/users", AddProduct);
app.use("/api/users", Payment);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server up and running on port ${port} !`));
```

Comment: Looks like a NodeJS setting issue, but why don't you just let your backend redirect to session.url? `res.redirect(303, session.url)`

Comment: @orakaro in which folder did you meant ?

Answer (score 0):

After few searches I found my answer. It was a silly mistake by me. I was using app.use("/api/users",Payment) at the server.js and was trying to fetch from("http://localhost:5000/create-checkout-session) rather than fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/users/create-checkout-session).Thanks for your concern and helping hand.